# The Norm of a Scalar Multiple of a Vector - proof

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am wondering if there is any equation proves that
\begin{equation} \| k \vec{u} \| = \mid k \mid \| \vec{u} \| \end{equation}
?

I couldn't find any proof in the Internet, only the equation. Where does it come from?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It can be proved from the definitions.

Comment: This is normally part of the definition of a norm i.e. a norm is a function which satisfies this, and some other conditions. Do you want to prove that some specific function is a norm? If so, which one?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I would like to solve it step by step. Which definition or condition should I quote? I know the definition of the norm of the vector but I think it is insufficient to solve this equation :)

Comment: @reformatorsystemu If you know the definition of a  norm, then this equation is part of the definition... So you've nothing to prove. An other story is: you're given a map and you need to verify that this map is a norm. In which case are you? Please update the question accordingly. If you're in the second case, you need to provide the given map in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Norms are defined as $||v||=\sqrt{<v,v>}$, so we can quickly find $<kv,kv>=k<v,kv>=k^2<v,v>^*=k^2<v,v>$ by using the axioms of the inner product. To finish we find $||kv||=\sqrt{k^2||v||^2}=k||v||$.